# Выбрать окно CMD и исполнить комманду

Tags: golang, cmd

**OS: Win 8.1 x32-64**

У меня есть 2 окна `cmd.exe`, первое - с обычными правами, второе - с админ правами, мне нужно выбрать второе окно с админ правами (Administrator: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe) и выполнить `cmd` команду в окне с админ правами.

Как я могу это сделать? Мне нужно что-то на подобии свитча окна, может быть как-то  через сисколы, не знаю, ничего подобного на просторах сети не находил, только вот как переключится на окно и выполнить команду я не знаю.

Нашел код на Golang, но не знаю как именно отправить комманду в окно cmd, и как именно называется окно администратора (Description):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/JamesHovious/w32"
)

var (
    moduser32               = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    procSetForegroundWindow = moduser32.NewProc("SetForegroundWindow")
    procFindWindowW         = moduser32.NewProc("FindWindowW")
)

const (
    KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN     = 0 //key UP
    KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
    KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002 //key UP
    KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004
    KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008 // scancode
)

type HWND uintptr

func auto() {
    hwnd, err := FindWindow("Windows Command Processor", "Console Window Host")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)

    sendkeys("Hello there!")
    sendkey(w32.VK_RETURN)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}

func main() {
    auto()
}

func sendkey(vk uint16) {
    var inputs []w32.INPUT
    inputs = append(inputs, w32.INPUT{
        Type: w32.INPUT_KEYBOARD,
        Ki: w32.KEYBDINPUT{
            WVk:         vk,
            WScan:       0,
            DwFlags:     KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN,
            Time:        0,
            DwExtraInfo: 0,
        },
    })

    inputs = append(inputs, w32.INPUT{
        Type: w32.INPUT_KEYBOARD,
        Ki: w32.KEYBDINPUT{
            WVk:         vk,
            WScan:       0,
            DwFlags:     KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
            Time:        0,
            DwExtraInfo: 0,
        },
    })
    w32.SendInput(inputs)
}

func sendkeys(str string) {
    var inputs []w32.INPUT
    for _, s := range str {
        inputs = append(inputs, w32.INPUT{
            Type: w32.INPUT_KEYBOARD,
            Ki: w32.KEYBDINPUT{
                WVk:         0,
                WScan:       uint16(s),
                DwFlags:     KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN | KEYEVENTF_UNICODE,
                Time:        0,
                DwExtraInfo: 0,
            },
        })

        inputs = append(inputs, w32.INPUT{
            Type: w32.INPUT_KEYBOARD,
            Ki: w32.KEYBDINPUT{
                WVk:         0,
                WScan:       uint16(s),
                DwFlags:     KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_UNICODE,
                Time:        0,
                DwExtraInfo: 0,
            },
        })
    }

    w32.SendInput(inputs)
}

func SetForegroundWindow(hwnd HWND) bool {
    ret, _, _ := procSetForegroundWindow.Call(
        uintptr(hwnd))

    return ret != 0
}

func FindWindow(cls string, win string) (ret HWND, err error) {
    lpszClass := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(cls)
    lpszWindow := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(win)

    r0, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procFindWindowW.Addr(), 2, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpszClass)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpszWindow)), 0)
    ret = HWND(r0)
    if ret == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            err = error(e1)
        } else {
            err = syscall.EINVAL
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: то есть, Вам нужно узнать, как послать окну нажатия клавиш?

Comment: @KoVadim ну что-то типа такого, просто другая программа подгружает окно от имени администратора, а я не могу запустить окно от имени администратора потому что я не знаю логина и пароля, и поэтому мне приходится выбирать такой путь. Так бы я просто сделал exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "start C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe") и не парился бы, но тут такие обстоятельства

Comment: очень похоже на что то вирусо-троянское.

Comment: @KoVadim нет, обновил описание, может быть вы поймете о чем я

Comment: Очень сомниваюсь что это возможно, ибо это дыра в ОС